# Proof of binomial coefficient formula.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

How can we prove that the number of  ways choosing $k$ elements among $n$ is    $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}$    with $k\leq n$?
This is an accepted fact in every book but i couldn't find a proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, let's first make sequences (*ordered* lists of distinct elements) of length $k$ from the $n$ element set.There are $n$ ways of picking the first element, $n-1$ ways of picking the second, ..., $n-k+1$ ways of picking the $k$th element. So there are $$n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$ such sequences.

But we want to count *unordered* lists, i.e., for each sequence, we want to identify the $k!$ permutations of its elements (each of which was counted separately above) as the same list. Hence the number of unordered lists is $$\frac{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{k!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Comment: I understand where the $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ and $k!$ come from I just do not understand logically speaking why you divide the two to switch from ordered to unordered. (+1)

Comment: @usainlightning maybe try writing out all the ordered sequences for some small $n$ and $k$ and grouping them by those that have the same numbers. You will see that each group has $k!$ sequences, so dividing by $k!$ is like shrinking each group into one "element" (the set of numbers in the sequences in that group). Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: @usainlightning another way to think about it: we have (# ordered sequences) = (#groups)(size of each group) where a group is the set of sequences with the same set of numbers. You want to count #groups and you have $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=$(# groups)$k!$.

Comment: Can you directly count unordered sequences? Instead of first counting ordered and then dividing out the orderings?

Comment: @user129393192 That's a good question and I'm not really sure of a good answer. The only thing I can think of right now is using induction (basically arguing that the count of $k$-subsets of an $n$-set satisfies Pascal's rule). I'm not sure that counts (no pun intended!)

Answer (score 6):

Notice that given $n$ objects $\{a_i\}$ and $n$ positions, there are $n$ possible positions for $a_n$. Once we have placed $a_n$, there are $n-1$ remaining positions for $a_{n-1}$. Once we have placed $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$, there are $n-2$ positions left for $a_{n-2}$, and so forth. Thus, there are
$$
n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot1=n!
$$
possible ways to arrange the $n$ items.

Suppose we divide the $n$ items into $k$ white objects and $n-k$ black objects. For each arrangement of the white and black objects that looks the same, there are $k!$ rearrangements of the white objects and $(n-k)!$ rearrangements of the black objects. Since there are $n!$ rearrangements of the $n$ objects, there must be
$$
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\binom{n}{k}
$$
arrangements of the $k$ white and $n-k$ black objects that look different.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it will help you go over the permutation formula first $\frac {n!}{\left( n-k \right)!}$ and then thinking about the adaptation we need if we are to disregard order. It is easier this way.

Answer (score 2):

First, for $k\leq n$ we must construct a $k$-permutation from an $n$-element set. We can choose the first item in $n$ ways, the second item in $n-1$ ways, whatever the choice of the first item,..., and the $k$th item in $n-(k-1)$ ways, whatever the choice of the first $k-1$ items. By the Multiplication Principle the $k$ items can be chosen in $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$ ways. We can rewrite this as $${n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)(n-k)!\over (n-k)!}={n!\over (n-k)!}.$$ Thus $P(n,k)={n!\over (n-k)!}$. By a $k$-permutation from a set $S$ of $n$ elements, we have an ordered arrangement of $k$ of the $n$ elements. Since we are concerned with the number of ways we can choose $k$ of the $n$ elements we want the number of unordered arrangements (subsets). Since each arrangement has length $k$ we can permute them in $k!$ ways. So the number of unordered arrangements of the elements of S is ${n!\over k!(n-k)!}$. Thus for $k\leq n$ $$C(n,k)={n!\over k!(n-k)!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

if you have $k$ number of black and $n-k$ white balls what is your change of getting 1 white then 1 black then 1 white... it is $\frac{(n-k)!k!}{n!}$ and if your change of getting $1$ combination is $\frac{(n-k)!k!}{n!}$ how many combinations are there answer is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$.this is how i think it but it can be flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is worth mentioning a method of solution that might appear a bit far-fetched, but which is an excellent introductory example to the theory of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), for which the book [generatingfunctionology by Herbert S. Wilf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf) is highly recommended.

Write $\dbinom{n}{k}$ for the number of choosing $k$ objects out of $n$. Consider the polynomial
$$
(1 + x_{1}) (1 + x_{2}) \cdots (1 + x_{n})
$$
in the $n$ indeterminates $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$. It is easy to convince oneself that this polynomial has exactly $\dbinom{n}{k}$ monomials of degree $k$. If one now sets $x_{1} = \dots = x_{n} = x$, where $x$ is another indeterminate, each such monomial reduces to $x^{k}$, so that one obtains that
$$
(1 + x)^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \dbinom{n}{k} x^{k}.
$$
Now use [Taylor's theorem for polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to obtain the required formula.

Let me stress that this might look totally overkill in this relatively simple setting. But the method has tremendous potential.

Answer (score -1):

Let $X$ be a nonempty finite set with $n$ elements. For the integer $s$ define

$$ \mathcal{P_s} (X) = \{ A \subset X \mid |A| = s\}$$

and for integer $r$ satisfying $0 \le r \lt n$ define

$$ \mathcal{B_r} (X) = \{ (A, b) \mid A \subset X \; \land \; |A| = r \; \land \; \displaystyle b \in A^{\complement }\}$$

Observe that $|\mathcal{B_r} (X)| =\, _n C _r \times (n-r)$.

Consider the function $\beta:\mathcal{B_r} (X) \to \mathcal{P_{r+1}} (X)$ defined by

$$ (A,b) \mapsto A \cup \{b\}$$

Now given any $B \in \mathcal{P_{r+1}} (X)$ we can write

$$ \beta^{-1}(B) = \{ (B\setminus\{b\},b) \mid b \in B\}$$

and so $\beta$ is a surjective function with a

$$ (r + 1) \text{ : } 1$$

mapping correspondence.

Therefore

$$\tag 1 |\mathcal{P_{r+1}} (X)| =\, _n C _{r+1} = \frac{_n C _r \times (n-r)}{r+1}$$

Since $_n C _0 = 1$, you can use induction to show that the number of subsets with $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements $(0 \le k \le n)$ is given by this formula:

$$ _n C _k = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{n-i}{i+1} \quad\text{(equal to } 1 \text{ when } k = 0 \text{)} $$

To complete the proof, fix $n$ and observe that

$ _n C_0 = \frac{n!}{0!(n-0)!}$

For $0 \le r \lt n$ assume that

$ _n C_r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

From $\text{(1)}$, all that is required to complete the (finite) induction is to show that

$$ \frac{n!}{(r+1)!\,(n-(r+1))!} = (\frac{n!}{r!\,(n-r)!})(\frac{n-r}{r+1})$$

But using the fact that $t! = t \times (t-1)!$,

$ (\frac{n!}{r!\,(n-r)!})(\frac{n-r}{r+1}) = \frac{(n-r)\,n!}{(r+1)\,r!\,(n-r)\,(n-r-1)!} = \frac{n!}{(r+1)!\,(n-(r+1))!}$

and we get the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

If you have 5 people (A, B, C, D & E) but wants to build a team of three people, the most number of ways you can do is 5x4x3= 60 ways. But realize that team ABC and CBA is basically same team.

So for three people, you can have 3x2x1=6 different combinations.

Meaning that, making a team with 5 poeple with 3 positions, you can have total (5x4x3) / (1x2x3) = 10 different combinations. This number 10 is the 3rd number on 5th row of Pascal's triangle. This basically tells us the number of combination we can have.

And (5x4x3) / (1x2x3) = 5! / (3! x 2!) = C (5, 3)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers, posted years ago.