# Why is nPr represented as n! / (n-r)!?

Tags: permutations, factorial

I recently started re-learning maths and have started with Combinatorics. I was trying to understand permutations and noticed that **`nPr` which is number of ways r elements can be picked and arranged out of n elements is equal to `n! / (n-r)!`**.

When I was going through the proof, I realised it's because of the multiplication `n * (n-1) * ... * (n-r+1)`

My questions is - since factorials can not be calculated without going through each multiplication, what are we gaining by denoting value of nPr in the 1st form instead of the 2nd.

- First - `n! / (n-r)!` - Communicates that an extra work of calculating (n-r)! is needed.
- Second - `n * (n-1) * ... * (n-r+1)` - No extra work and easy to understand.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In some cases the first formula will make symbolic computation easier.  Numeric computation is a different matter.

Comment: What does `symbolic computation ` mean?

Comment: Computing with symbols, as you do in algebra.

Comment: Can you give a reference for me to understand more? From what I understand, you can only come up with formula using symbols, but to really evaluate something, you need to perform the actual computations.

Answer (score 1):

In maths, different presentations of the same thing might yield different insights. In this case, you might derive $^nP_r$ from $^nC_r$ as follows:

We know that $^nC_r$ counts the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from $n$ objects, without caring about the order you choose them from.

But suppose now we want to care about the order. There are $r!$ ways to order the $r$ chosen objects. So we have $$^nP_r = {}^nC_r\times r!$$

Recall [the formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/565248/463578) for

$$^nC_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

so we have $$^nP_r=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

Comment: I agree about the different way of understanding something but your suggestion would demand an analysis of how we evaluate and understand `nCr`. I have not done that yet so won't comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "extra work". The variant with factorials is certainly easier to write by hand. And on a calculator with factorials it is much easier to type, significantly reducing the risk of human error.

Comment: Easier to type, but you won't get a result for $200P2$ for instance, though it's only $39800$.

Comment: So the purpose is solely for humans? Maths / machine wise there is no advantage, infact is extra work. Right?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal It's much worse than extra work: in floating point, you will get an overflow even for moderate $n$. But for "pure" maths, we know many things on $n!$ that we can reuse. For instance Stirling's formula.

Comment: By "extra work" I mean the number of computations needed to evaluate the answer.

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal My point is: extra computation, **and** extremely large intermediate values.

Answer (score 0):

No I do not think you are.
But in practice, - your calculation is what we all, - and our calculators does.

The notation is just a lot easier. As you have demonstrated. :)